# Android convert String to String[]

Tags: android, arrays

I have a String

```
["first","second","third"]
```

And I need to convert it to a String[] so I can loop through it.

I've seen people suggest

```
String[] mArray = {mString};
```

But that doesn't work for me, do I need to format my String differently first before converting it?

Comment: I have added the sample code in my answer. If needed you can use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this code

```
JSONArray temp = new JSONArray(mString);
String[] mArray = temp.join(",").split(",");
```

Comment: I've just realized I can use a JSONArray rather than String[], I can just loop the JSONArray.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) in String class.

If you wanna do that

```
1) remove all "
2) take substring inorder to remove the [ and ]
3) Then make use of split method.
```

*Sample Code*

`String tmp="[\"first\",\"second\",\"third\"]".replace("\"", "");`
`String tm[]=tmp.substring(1, tmp.length()-1).split(",");`
`for(int i=0;i<tm.length;i++)`
`System.out.println(tm[i]);`